# Повлияют ли неаннотированные изображения существующих классов, на обучение модели Faster R-CNN

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Нужно обучить модель для обнаружения объектов.
Допустим у меня есть 300 изображений для аннотаций с изображениями различных животных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении может быть много различных классов: Кошка, Собака, Заяц, Волк, Лиса т.д.
Допустим, мне нужны только Кошка и Собака, я аннотирую 300 изображений с 2 классами `["CAT", "DOG"]`.
После аннотации и формирования датасета, мне присылают ещё 300 изображений и просят добавить класс "ЗАЯЦ".

**Вопрос: если я аннотирую только новые 300 изображений и не стану возвращаться к первым 300, на которых так-же может встречаться заяц(не аннотированный). Повлияет ли это на результаты обучения модели обнаружения объектов?**

**P.S Подразумевается, что датасет для обучения будет передан разом, то есть, мы не дообучаем модель на последующих 300 используя к примеру Fine tuning, а сразу обучаем на 600, просто после первых 300 изображений, добавляется еще один класс.**

Или же, лучше/можно обучить в начале на 300, а затем просто дообучить на еще один класс?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но без знания хотя бы структуры этой нейросети так вот сложно сказать. Проще было бы проверить экспериментом, мне кажется )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Универсальный ответ: "Повлияет" :-)

Другое дело как и насколько? Если у нас 600 фото (там 600 котов, 600 собак и 600 зайцев) и мы "потеряли" первых 300 зайцев, то (как минимум) нейросеть скорее всего лучше выучит котов-собак (просто потому, что их больше). Но у тебя (видимо) в голове вопрос: "А не увидим ли мы **существенное** ухудшение на зайцах?" Я не пробовал эту структуру нейросети и мне трудно прогнозировать. В стандартных архитектурах сегментации, где есть "кот", "собака", "фон" и добавляем "заяц" нейросеть точно ухудшит результат, т.к. нейронка будет получать противоречивый сигнал обучения фон/заяц. По аналоги можно утверждать, что **твоя loss функция будет штрафовать нейросеть за зайца**, которого (якобы!) нет. Поэтому мое мнение - да, точность зайцев упадет. Более того - общая точность собак/кошек тоже может [незначительно] просесть.

Возможно есть смысл такой схемы обучения: обучаем на последних 300 фотках (где есть все классы), после этого прогоняем через нейросеть на первых 300 фотках (заодно своими глазами смотрим насколько хорошо получились коты/собаки) и где нужно корректируем ответ по зайцам. Получаем полноценный обучающий dataset из 600 фотографий на которых и дообучаем нейросеть. По результатам анализа обучения возможно захочется скорректировать loss функцию и еще раз дообучить.

Второй вариант: сразу поменять вычисление loss функции так, что бы на первых 300 картинках не штрафовались зайцы вообще. (Потенциально это можно. При обучении в ответе нейросети все ответы "заяц" меняем на ответ "фон" и тогда loss не сможет штрафовать за зайца.)

Comment: Скорее всего, сеть просто найдёт различие между размеченными и неразмеченными зайцами) Но ответ очень подробный, супер!